# finding one week Data

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

My task is finding maximum date and from that day show previous week data. in my 1st query it goes only on date 2022-12-01. i want 2nd query output. Any suggestion how to solve.

Mysql query is:

```
Select 
   date, local from price_trend  mar
inner join 
   location man on mar.id =man.id
 where
    commodity_id=0 and mandi_id in(3)  and  
    date between ((select date_sub(max(date), INTERVAL 7 day)from price_trend ))
    and (date(select(max(date) from price_trend ) ) ;
```

I am getting this output:

| date | location |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-03 | Ahmedabad |
| 2022-12-02 | Ahmedabad |
| 2022-12-01 | Ahmedabad |

[Output Image of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN4tk.png)

when i removes subquery max(date). and directly put maximum date it return whole week data and it goes previous month also.

```
Select 
   date, location 
from price_trend  mar
inner join 
   location man on mar.id =man.id
where commodity_id=0 and mandi_id in(3)  and  
   date between (date_sub('2022-12-03', INTERVAL 7 day))
   and (date('2022-12-03')) ;
```

i am getting this output:

| date | location |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-03 | Ahmedabad |
| 2022-12-02 | Ahmedabad |
| 2022-12-01 | Ahmedabad |
| 2022-11-30 | Ahmedabad |
| 2022-11-29 | Ahmedabad |
| 2022-11-28 | Ahmedabad |
| 2022-11-26 | Ahmedabad |

[output Image of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So0FA.png)

Comment: you first sql statement is incorrect, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/eqD7ZzCw   (error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select(max(date) from price_trend ) )'" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calculating the cutoff date for each `local` in a subquery, then filtering on that field:

```
SELECT * FROM (
Select 
   date, local, DATE_ADD(MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY local), INTERVAL -7 DAY) as mxDt
from price_trend  mar
inner join 
   location man on mar.id =man.id
 where
    commodity_id=0 and mandi_id in(3))
WHERE date >= mxDt
```